# Emacs Latex mode error "symbol's function definition is void : latex/setup-keybinds

Tags: emacs, latex

I get this error when I try to load the .tex files in Latex or Tex mode.

```
symbol's function definition is void : latex/setup-keybinds
```

Checked all files but dont know why error is coming as everthing was working ok before.

What is the source of this error ? How can I find which package or settings are missing ?

Comment: If you search your source code for that function (with a search utility), you'll find one of two things -- it won't be there, or it will be there in a library and that library hasn't loaded.  If it's the former, find the function and/or missing library and add it to your collection.  If it is the latter, load the library and problem solved.  You're probably missing `(require 'name-of-library-containing-the-missing-function)` or the library isn't in your `load-path` (so add the applicable `load-path` or move the library to an existing `load-path` that is valid).

Comment: @lawlist Thanks for the reply. The problem here is that there error is not the name of either a package or a command. It might be in some subset of package and debugging also doesnt which line is causing the error.

Comment: If you are having difficulty searching your source files of Emacs and third-party installs, then you can also do a search with Google for the function name and probably track down the library name that way.  However, you really should learn how to search your own files on the hard drive -- you are looking for a file containing the word `latex/setup-keybinds`  Here is what Google reveals if you search for `"defun latex/setup-keybinds"`:  https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/latex-extra/blob/master/latex-extra.el  So -- do you have the library `latex-extra.el` and is it in your `load-path`?

Comment: And, if you have the library `latex-extra.el` and if it is in your `load-path`, then do you have a `(require 'latex-extra)` somewhere after your `load-path` has been adjusted to point to wherever `latex-extra.el` is located (if not already set correctly)?

Comment: @lawlist On windows, i usually have to open all the files to search them for a particular word. Do you have any tips for searching within files ? Commands line args ?  I searched google for the error but not for the specific command.  You can add that as an answer and will accept. Thanks.

Comment: @lawlist I think latex extra was removed when reshuffling folders and it might be required as a dependency for some other package as i dont add it directly in the config. And didnt know that was the missing package.

Comment: The instructions for that library state that it's available on Melpa, so that may be another way for you to install it again if it's not already on your hard drive.  `grep` and versions based on it are usually available on most operating systems, and Emacs has a few variations that are built-in -- just do a Google search for `emacs grep` or `windows grep`.  I've been using Emacs for more than a year and I still haven't been able to get rid of SublimeText which has a search utility that can comb through files like `grep` does.

Comment: @lawlist Already did that. Dired mode is supposed to be helpful and there are commands to search in all open buffers but sometimes they dont work or not as efficient. Thanks a lot for helping locate the error :)

Comment: @lawlist I would rather say I dont know how to use emacs multifile search well enough yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an error message appears in Emacs stating that `symbol's function definition is void ...`, the usual cases are as follows:

- The library containing the function named in the error message is missing.
- The library containing the function named in the error message is not in the `load-path`.
- The library containing the function named in the error message has not been loaded using something like `(require 'name-of-library-without-the-el-at-the-end)`.  The `load-path` for the location where the library is installed must be adjusted *before* the `require` statement.  Rather than adjusting the `load-path` for a new directory, it is also possible to simply save or move the library to an existing directory that is already in the `load-path`.

In this particular case, a Google search for `"defun latex/setup-keybinds"` indicates the missing function is from a third-party library called `latex-extra.el` -- http://www.github.com/Bruce-Connor/latex-extra/blob/master/latex-extra.el  Prior to using Google, however, searching the hard-drive for file contents with a utility such as `grep` for the name of the missing function `latex/setup-keybinds` usually gives good clues.

The instructions on the home page for `latex-extra.el` indicate that it is available on Melpa, so reinstalling would be another option if tracking down the library on the hard-drive was unfruitful.

Comment: And +1 for windows grep

Comment: Did you know about the lgrep command in emacs ? M-x lgrep. It can search for a string in all the files in a directory.

Comment: Here is a little something I put together yesterday to customize my own search string and decide how many context lines I want to see -- it's only a first draft and I've only tested it a few times:  `(defun my-grep () (interactive) (let* ( (search-term (read-string "term:  " "test")) (search-path (read-string "path:  " default-directory)) (initial-grep-command "grep -inIEr --color=ALWAYS -C2") (grep-command (concat initial-grep-command " " search-term " " search-path)) ) (grep grep-command) (with-current-buffer (get-buffer "*grep*") (font-lock-mode 1) (setq truncate-lines t))))`

Comment: My normal dilemma is that I'm usually customizing `elisp` files and testing the changes as I go, which frequently results in Emacs breaking until it's fixed, so I end up using another search utility outside of Emacs.  I suppose the alternative would be to have a separate instance of Emacs with a separate set of initialization files so that I can use it while the test Emacs is broken.

Comment: This works well. Thanks for sharing this code. I also learned about window grep tools like grepwin which makes grep available on PC.

Comment: What I generally do is to add all new lisp code to a separate .el file and load it the last in main .emacs file. That ways if there is any error, I only need to check or uncomment that line. As functions get tested, I move them to another .el file to keep code manageable and make debugging faster.